# geo-targeted push notification with android and nodejs via GCM

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to create an android app (iOS in the future) which will send push notifications to nearby user if an event is created within that user's current location (eg:2km radius)

Currently what I have in mind is to have the android app connected to nodejs server and mongodb for storing the events created.

However, I've been trying to figure out how and what is the best way to notify nearby user once the event is created. Here's my idea of doing it currently:

1. Listen for a change in mongodb (whenever someone created a new event),
2. Send request to get all user's location and its specified radius of alert
3. Query and send push notification to users within the specified radius of       alert. (via Google Cloud Messaging)

By using this method, users that enter the specified radius after the event has been created will not be able to receive the push notification.

Is there any other easier or better way achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents:

It depends on how many "events" you intend to create and how these "events" are created and who creates these "events", but i would go for this solution:

- Store all your "events" in the **Google Firebase Database**
- The Google Firebase Database automatically syncs all of the "events" with all your devices that have the Android/iOS App installed
- Let the App itself decide, if one or more "events" are within
  the radius of alert or not
- Let the App notify the user
- If your app users also creates the "events", **you don't need any server
  at all**
- If you have an admin who creates the "events", you maybe need a small
  web app to feed the "events" into the Google Firebase Database and to delete them

The open questions for me are:

- How many "events" will be created? Dozens, thousands, billions...?
- Who creates the "events"? The users? An administrator?
- Can the "events" become obsolete? If yes, who deletes outdated "events" from the database?